# PHP / MySQL Grouped Query, how to group second query with first?

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble figuring out how to group a selection in a while loop after a second query (within while loop). All info below.

My Table

```
CREATE TABLE MTAs (
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
agcid int(3) NOT NULL,
ad int(1) NOT NULL,
fqdn varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`as` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
ps varchar(5) NOT NULL,
dn varchar(10) NOT NULL,
npa varchar(3) NOT NULL,
nxx varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Sample Data

```
(1590305265, 2, 1, 'dlnirwtiv.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '719587xxxx', '719', '587', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305266, 2, 1, 'kwror4203.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406290xxxx', '406', '290', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305267, 2, 1, 'o0ontf472.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406556xxxx', '406', '556', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305268, 2, 1, 'twron2507.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '719992xxxx', '719', '992', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305269, 2, 1, 'qo3pkk149.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406299xxxx', '406', '299', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305270, 2, 1, 'wqqblbmij.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406309xxxx', '406', '309', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305271, 2, 1, 'c0woqk554.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '719691xxxx', '719', '691', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305272, 2, 1, 'hsmt5b940.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '970639xxxx', '970', '639', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305273, 2, 1, 'yfbl3rl8e.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406656xxxx', '406', '656', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305274, 2, 1, 'w5mkoc117.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406361xxxx', '406', '361', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
(1590305275, 2, 1, 'ulp5frrgj.xx.some.domain', 'ACT', 'UNA', '406563xxxx', '406', '563', '2018-03-22 17:15:01'),
```

I have this query

```
$sql = "SELECT AGCs.name AS agcname, npa, nxx, COUNT( npa ) AS ooscount
FROM MTAs
INNER JOIN AGCs ON AGCs.id = MTAs.agcid
WHERE agcid =  '".$_GET['agcid']."'
GROUP BY npa, nxx
ORDER BY  `ooscount` DESC";
```

And in my while loop, I then perform another query on data to correlate the NPA/NXX to a rate center/city.

```
SELECT rcabbr, s.l_state
FROM endoff
INNER JOIN state s ON s.s_state = state
WHERE npa =  '".$npa."'
AND nxx =  '".$nxx."' LIMIT 1";
```

This groups counts to a particular NPA/NXX

This gives me an output like this.

```
AGC OOS Count   Location    Rate Center NPA NXX
agc04   246 WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 298
agc04   170 MERRILL WISCONSIN   715 536
agc04   119 WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 842
agc04   116 WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 675
agc04   103 WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 845
agc04   85  WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 848
```

What I need to do now, is group all similar cities/counts into a single container like so:

```
AGC OOS Count   Location    Rate Center NPA NXX
agc04   672 WAUSAU  WISCONSIN   715 298
                                715 842
                                715 675
                                715 845
                                715 848
agc04   170 MERRILL WISCONSIN   715 536
```

I'm at a loss for how I would even go about accomplishing this due to table structures. The second query for state/city/rate center is from a LERG database (telephony data). I'm guessing I'd need to do this within PHP.

---EDIT---

I've made some progress. I changed my query to this:

```
SELECT a.name AS agcname, m.npa, m.nxx, COUNT( m.npa ) AS ooscount, 
e.rcabbr, s.l_state FROM k.MTAs m
INNER JOIN k.AGCs a ON a.id = m.agcid
INNER JOIN endoffice.endoff e on e.npa = m.npa and e.nxx = m.nxx
INNER JOIN endoffice.state s ON s.s_state = e.state       
      WHERE agcid =  '3'
      GROUP BY e.rcabbr,m.npa
      ORDER BY  ooscount DESC
```

This is almost what I want:

```
agc03   909 585 1047    BIGBEAR CY  CALIFORNIA
agc03   775 686 892     RENO        NEVADA
agc03   909 878 359     BIGBEAR LK  CALIFORNIA
agc03   775 298 252     CRYSTALBAY  NEVADA
agc03   909 527 195     UPLAND      CALIFORNIA
```

Trying to get the other NXX's to display under my group. For reference, with original query, there was 7 BIGBEAR CY rows, so this is grouping properly now with the exception of listing the other NPA NXXs

Comment: I need to mention the second query is to a separate database on same server.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, you can access tables in any database by using the syntax `dbname.tablename` in the query.

Comment: I've made some progress on what I'm trying to do. Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Join all 4 of your tables to get the per-NPA/NXX information. Then join this with a subquery that gets the totals per rate-center.

```
SELECT a.name, x.total_ooscount, e.rcabbr, s.l_state, m.npa, m.nxx
FROM MTAs AS m
JOIN AGCs AS a ON a.id = m.agcid
JOIN endoff AS e ON e.npa = m.npa AND e.nxx = m.nxx
JOIN state AS s ON s.s_state = e.state
JOIN (
    SELECT e.rcabbr, s.l_state, COUNT(*) AS total_ooscount
    FROM MTAs AS m
    JOIN endoff AS e ON e.npa = m.npa AND e.nxx = m.nxx
    JOIN state AS s ON s.s_state = e.state
    WHERE m.agcid = {$_GET['agcid']}
    GROUP BY e.rcabbr, s.l_state
) AS x ON x.rcabbr = e.rcabbr AND x.l_state = s.l_state
WHERE m.agcid = {$_GET['agcid']}
ORDER BY s.l_state, e.rcabbr
```

When you're displaying the results, save the previous row's `rcabbr` and `l_state` in variables. If the current row is the same, leave all those columns blank.

Comment: So, this looks like it essentially spits out 1 row for each find? Nothing is grouped. I had this same thing essentially before I did the group by with my original query. Today learned I don't need the second query as I can left join the other DB.

Comment: The grouping is in the subquery, it calculates the totals for each rate center. You don't need grouping in the main query, just ordering.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data for all 4 tables?

Comment: Think this is correct. I had to scrape a lot of data due to some sensitive stuff. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f204d9/1

Comment: I've updated my sqlfiddle with more of what I've been toying with and also more real data (multiple NPA/NXXs within same rate center, which I some how didnt do yesterday). So the data in it now is more accurate.

Comment: Apparently I need to redo it and give a new URL. Didn't realize it would not stay.. :| Heres a new url: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/806c9f/2

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to resolve my issue. It was more of a PHP fix than MySQL, but figured I would share.

```
agc05olvemo ASHLAND OREGON  541201  55
                            541552
                            541708
                            541482
                            541488
```

I had to move the OOS count to the end in order to achieve this. I'm still confused about this, but managed to make it work.

Here is the query in use:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.name AS agcname, m.npa, m.nxx, COUNT( m.npa ) AS ooscount,e.rcabbr,s.l_state
      FROM MTAs m
      INNER JOIN AGCs a ON a.id = m.agcid
      LEFT JOIN endoffice.endoff e ON e.npa = m.npa
      INNER JOIN endoffice.state s ON s.s_state = e.state
      AND e.nxx = m.nxx
      WHERE agcid =  '".$agcid."'
      GROUP BY npa, nxx
      ORDER BY rcabbr ASC";
```

Here is my crappy PHP to achieve the desired result. (don't criticize my aweful code, I'm not a developer by nature. :))

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $agcrow = "";
  $agcname = $row['agcname'];
  $ooscount = $row['ooscount'];
  $npa = $row['npa'];
  $nxx = $row['nxx'];
  $rcabbr = $row['rcabbr'];
  $l_state = $row['l_state'];
  $npanxx = "".$npa."".$nxx."";

  if (isset($rc) && $rc != $rcabbr) {
      $agcrow .= "                       </div><div class=\"divTableCell\">".$rcoos."</div>\n                     </div>\n";
      unset($rcoos);
      unset($rc);
      unset($st);

  }    

  if (!isset($rc)) {
      $rc = $rcabbr;
      $st = $l_state;
      $agcrow .= "\n                     <div class=\"divTableRow\">     
                   <div class=\"divTableCell\">" . $agcname. "</div>      
                   <div class=\"divTableCell\">".$rc."</div>      
                   <div class=\"divTableCell\">".$l_state."</div>
                   <div class=\"divTableCell\"><A href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?agcid=".$agcid."&npa=".$npa."&nxx=".$nxx."\">".$npanxx."</a><BR>\n";
  } else {
      $agcrow .= "                                                 <A href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?agcid=".$agcid."&npa=".$npa."&nxx=".$nxx."\">".$npanxx."</a><BR>\n";   
  }
  $rcoos = $rcoos + $ooscount;

  echo $agcrow;
}
```